# Is there some way to "de-register" Quicktime for MP4 files?

Tags: high-sierra, video, quicktime

I have done this:

[image: open with]

(then click Open) about 4 times now. And yet the last time I clicked on an MP4 file it opened up in Quicktime. It's like OSX is ignoring what I told it to do. When I look at the file with Get Info it says it is an MPEG-4 movie. The default option under "Open With" is Quicktime.

This is aggravating. How do I convince OSX that I really meant it when I checked "Always Open With"?

High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: Always open with on the open file window only applies to that file

Answer (score 5):

Find one mp4 file. Right click, Get Info or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>I</kbd>

If not already set, select VLC in Open With, then click Change all...

[image]

There's also the old faithful, [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) which reports have said no longer works in High Sierra, but I just tested & it appears to.

[image]

Comment: I just did this with 2 mp4s on my computer. One is set to "Open with" VLC and the other is Quicktime. The "Kind" of one is MPEG-4 File and the other is MPEG-4 **Movie**. I changed it but is there some list of registered file types in OSX?

Comment: There's [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) which I'd heard no longer worked in High Sierra, but I just tested it & it seems to.

Comment: ok I'll give that a try tonight or tomorrow night